# How can I break loop from callback function in node js?

Tags: node.js

I have asynchronous query in Node.js. Variable `sq3` is a connection variable.
For example something like this:

```
for (var i in res) {
  if (i == 1) {
    sq3.query("SELECT * from students;",

      function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          if (res.length == 1) {
            //do something
          } else {
            //break for
          }
        }
      });

    sq3.end();
  }
}
```

How can I break from callback function?
Thanks

Comment: I want to break loop for, not just return from callback function

Comment: then simple break statement should have worked for that

Comment: I've already tried all that simple ways and it doesn't work

Comment: simple break doesn't work because it is callback function and loop for is outside that function

Comment: It's not possible, but it's also pointless to try to break a loop from an async callback... The loop will be done by the time any callback gets the chance to run **edit:** assuming sq3 is async

Comment: It's bad practice to launch async calls in a for loop like this.  None of them get to do their work before all of them are spun up.  This is cool if there are only a few, but if their are many(1000s, 10000s,...) it is very bad.  Try doing your loop recursively instead of iteratively.  This will also allow you to use your break.

Comment: @PP: it is a perfectly valid question, the question is just deeper than the OP believes.  What he believes is a question about breaking for loops, is really a question about async callbacks.  But if he knew that, he likely wouldn't need to ask the question.

Answer (score 5):

Just do it like this, using recursion instead of loops.  Not only does this allow you to achieve the logic you want.  It also doesn't spin up a bunch of async requests at once.  They execute in turn, but asynchronously, so it's still performant.

```
function lookatEntireResponse(res) {

    function lookAtItemInResponse(item) {
        if(item == 1) {
            sq3.query("SELECT * from students;",

                function(err, res) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                       throw err;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if(res.length==1)
                        {
                            doSomething(item);
                            lookAtItemInResponse(res.shift());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //just don't call the next lookAtItemInResponse function, effectively same thing as "break;"
                        }

                    }
                });

            sq3.end();
        } else {
            lookAtItemInResponse(res.shift());
        }
    }

    lookAtItemInResponse(res.shift());

}
```

You can consider throttling simultaneous requests with similar logic (say allowing 10 such requests per lookAtItem call.  This way you can achieve a hybrid of the two methods, and then just optimize the number of simultaneous requests for performance.  The Async library makes stuff like this easier.

Answer (score 0):

In your code fragment, you can't break from the within the callback function. In node.js, callback functions run at an unspecified later time on the same thread. This means but the time you callback function executes, the for loop has long since finished.

To get the effect you want, you need to restructure you code quite significantly. Here's an example of how you could do it (untested!!). The idea is to keep calling `doSomething()` with the list of items, shrinking it by one element each time until the desired result is achieved (your break condition).

```
function doSomething(res)
{
    while (res.length > 0)
    {
        i = res.shift(); // remove the first element from the array and return it
        if (i == 1)
        {
            sq3.query("SELECT * from students;",
                function(err, res) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                       throw err;
                    }

                    if (res.length==1)
                    {
                        //do something

                        // continue with the remaining elements of the list
                        // the list will shrink by one each time as we shift off the first element
                        doSomething(res);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // no need to break, just don't schedule any more queries and nothing else will be run
                    }
                });

            sq3.end();
            break; // break from the loop BEFORE the query executes. We have scheduled a callback to run when the query completes.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The iterative loop is just to locate items equivalent to 1, which are then queried in the database. Once the database query completes it either terminates or continues iterating through the remaining elements until it finds another equal to 1. So I'm quite sure it is equivalent.

Comment: Actually I've just realised that the `res` variable passed in to the original function is then reused as a parameter to the query callback function. I didn't notice the same variable name was being reused, so my code won't above work as it is. I'm not sure what the OP was trying to achieve, but my basic solution of recursively `shift`ing through the list still holds!

Comment: Yes, now you see it. I was just double checking myself. Your logical idea is correct, and actually equivalent to mine.  Your iterative loop  addition(if combined correctly with the recursion to not re-visit values) may actually help performance(microoptimization).  And you did mention it was untested, so I'll give you that one :) If you edit your answer in a silly way, I'll remove my downvote given that comment

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  if (i == 1) {
    sq3.query("SELECT * from students;",

      function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          if (res.length == 1) {
            //do something
          } else {
            i = res.length
          }
        }
      });

    sq3.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation in addition to your code snippet?

Comment: the question is that, he want to break the outer loop inside the sq3.query() callback. But 'break' keyword not working inside callback function. So without break statement the outer loop only break when this "i < res.length" condition false. Thats way I am changing the "i" value with the res.length, that is inside else block "i = res.length"