# How to breaking a for loop inside a callback function Node JS

Tags: node.js

please help!

How to breaking if available true?

I use node js tcp-ping module.

My code

```
var tcpp = require('tcp-ping');

    let arr = ['imap:143', 'imap:993', 'mail:143', 'mail:993'];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {

        let alias = arr[i].split(":")[0];
        let port = arr[i].split(":")[1];
        
        tcpp.probe(alias+'.aol.com', parseInt(port), function(err, available) {
            if(available){
                //need break
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358481/how-can-i-break-loop-from-callback-function-in-node-js

Comment: A bit of news for you.  For `for` loop has already finished LONG before your asynchronous callback gets called.  So, you can't use this type of structure if you really want to stop the `for` loop based on an `asynchronous result.  To understand how this works, your `for` loop runs to completion calling all the `tcpp.probe()` functions.  Then, sometime later, long after the `for` loop has finished, the callbacks you passed to `tcpp.probe()` will start getting called.  To help you with a solution that could work, we need to know what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: i need to ping ports from array and find one available, then abort the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to send the probes one at a time, wait to see if you got the right response and if so, stop and if not, go to the next, then it's easiest to use `await` and promises like this:

```
const tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const tcpp_probe = promisify(tcpp.probe);

async function probe(arr) {
    for (const item of arr) {
        const [alias, port] = item.split(":");
        try {
            const available = await tcpp_probe(alias + '.aol.com', parseInt(port));
            if (available) {
                // return whatever you want or act on the result here
                return alias;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // decide what to do here if you get an error
            // this will log the error and then continue with the loop
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    // no matches
    return null;
}
```

And, then you would call it like this:

```
let arr = ['imap:143', 'imap:993', 'mail:143', 'mail:993'];
probe(arr).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I like your answer because the async/await makes it easy to read/understand. I'm not sure about why you would use try/catch and then switch to .then syntax. Would you not want to perform an action with the result in the body of the if statement in the success block?

Comment: @Hyetigran - That's up to you.  You didn't say what you wanted to do with the result.  I was attempting to make a reusable function that could be called and then the caller could use the result.  If you want to just embed the action inside the function you can choose to do that.  You didn't show the action so we had no idea what that was.

Comment: Thanks for the response, btw I'm not OP. I was asking a follow up question because generally I've been told to use either .then or try/catch. Therefor it was interesting to see it being combined in your example and I wasn't sure if it had extra benefit/util to do so.

Comment: @Hyetigran - Well, you can only use `await` inside an `async` function so when I call this function from the top level, you can't use `await` there (until top-level await comes to nodejs) so I'm using `.then()`.  The guidance is to not mix `await` and `.then()` in the same function, not that you can't use both in your program for different purposes.  The point of `await` inside the function is that it's way easier to sequence async operations in a `for` loop with `await`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, but how do you make the function synchronous?

Comment: @DmitriyPavlov - You can't make a function synchronous that gets its result asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use async/await or promises, you could try calling your function recursively.

```
var probeAll = function(index, callback, err, available){
    // Terminal Condition
    if (available){
        // do something
        callback(available);
        return;
    }
    let arr = ['imap:143', 'imap:993', 'mail:143', 'mail:993'];
    let alias = arr[index].split(":")[0];
    let port = arr[index].split(":")[1];
    
    tcpp.probe(alias+'.aol.com', parseInt(port), function(err, available){
        probeAll(index++, callback, err, available);
    });
};

// First probeAll call
probeAll(0, function(avail){
    // Do something
});
```

Edit: you very well may need to tweak this to handle errors i.e. if none of the calls come back available, etc.